# Firefox opening blank (crashed) tabs in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-18.04, tabs

I'm facing a strange problem with my Firefox.

Sometimes, when I open a new tab from a link (or even a new tab), it just opens a blank page (or eternal loading page) and I need to click in the link again and again and again until it actually open.

It occurs randomly. I made a little GIF to show the error on my environment. The number of blank tabs are also random (7 tabs until get a working one on the example).

[image: firefox opening 7 tabs until get a working one]

Detail: On the crashed tabs, the shortcut to reload (F5) does not work at all, it is actually a "dead" tab.

I already disabled all my extensions and also tried on anonymous mode and the error persists. The console log on blank tabs does not show anything.

The same Firefox version on Fedora 29 environment works very fine, but Ubuntu is making the use of Firefox very annoying.

I'm googling around web and here at SU, but didn't find anything. Anyone had a similar problem or have any tip on what it could be?

Specs:

- *Ubuntu 18.04.4*
- *Firefox 75.0*

Firefox updated to <s>75</s> <s>76</s> <s>77</s> 78. Problem persists.

Make new user. Run as new user. Problem persists.

Comment: You may also find an answer if you search at the Q&A site for Ubuntu, https://askubuntu.com

Comment: @K7AAY I tried to find something at Ask Ubuntu but didn't found any answer to my problem. Do you think that my question fits better there?

Comment: It's acceptable in either site. There's more concentrated Ubuntu know-how there, which is why I suggested checking. If you want it moved, you can click on the [flag] link and ask for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for the problem. The following tip finally solves this annoying problem and it could help someone with similar problem.

The solution is just turn off the recommended performance settings in the preferences menu (about:preferences#general).

[image: Preferences settings with performance option disabled]

I'm not sure about the exact behavior of this option and I don't now for now if it brings some drawbacks, but , at least, the tabs  are not broken anymore.

***EDIT:***

I'll keep this answer here, but is good to know that after some weeks using this firefox configuration, unfortunatelly it didn't solve the problem. The solution reduces the problem, but it still happens sometimes.

I also found that the problem is also reduced using the [firefox developer edition](https://www.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/developer/) (80.0b8 (64-bits)). Not solved, but it occurs just sometimes.